# Is there a way to not focus on element when changing display with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript code that changes the CSS `display` property of an element when a button is clicked to create a multi column view. However, I don't want the item to come to focus when its display is changed. The scrolling makes it hard for users to see top of the page.

Is there a way to make Javascript not focus on the element who `display` property is changed?

Here is the javascript snippet and the HTML twig.

```js
function openTabEvent(evt, tabName, callback) {

    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    location.hash = tabName;
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";

    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    
}
```

```html
 {% block tab %}
                <div class="tab">
                    {% for module in page.collection() %}
                        <div class="tablinks button_a" onclick="openTab(event, '{{ 
module.menu|hyphenize }}')"  id="{{ module.menu|hyphenize }}_button">{{module.menu}}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% endblock %}

                {% block columns %}
                <div class="columns">
                    {% for module in page.collection() %}
                        <div id="{{ module.menu|hyphenize }}" class="content">
                            <div class="column">
                                {{ module.content|raw }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preventDefault function in your event logic that causes focusing

Something like this

```
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
}
```